# Control Android Camera using Arduino over Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-nano, wireless, android, hc-05

I want to Control Android Mobile Camera shutter using Arduino over Bluetooth. So i can click photos using arduino.

I have HC-05 Bluetooth Module and **Arduino Nano/Arduino leonardo**.
[image]

The Connection as shown in figure.

The Android mobile successfully connected to Bluetooth Module but i am not found any code to control camera or any button on android mobile.

Comment: You'll need an Android APP to interface with the bluetooth and receive instructions to control the camera. Maybe the play store has something. If not, you'll have to learn Android programming.

Comment: Is there any code available which can control android mobile volume buttons from arduino??

Comment: What have volume buttons got to do with anything?

Comment: Volume buttons can also use for camera shutter, so if arduino can control volume buttons then it also use as camera shutter.

Comment: I think you don't understand how things work. An app may read the buttons and use them to do things like activate the shutter, but you cannot "control" a button from inside software. A button is an external physical thing.

Comment: Did you look on the play store for anything suitable? If you didn't find anything then chances are there is nothing. So you will have to learn Android programming. I am sure there are plenty of bluetooth examples, and plenty of camera examples. Your task will be to work out how to combine the two into a custom app. And this isn't the place for that, since it has nothing to do with Arduino.

Comment: Yes i already search on play store and there are nothing related to this. That's why i am asking here, Because i am not a android programmer.

Comment: I think those cheap BT shutter buttons act like a keyboard, and send the spacebar keycode (if I remember correctly)

Answer (score 1):

I am trying out [Camera Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teapps.camerapro&hl=en). It allows shutter control on Android over Bluetooth. I just got an Uno R3 and and HC-05 so I have not wired it up to try it.

There are example sketch and detailed docs [here](http://www.tequnique.com/camerapro.php).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Link-only answers are generally considered not good because the link may disappear. Add some relevant info from the link to your question, please. Thank you and enjoy our site!

Comment: Programming Android is too much work (PITA, really). I like your solution even if I have to pay for it. I grow tired of downloading IDE updates every other week, dealing with API changes from one release to next one, and having to redesign apps to the latest fad ("material" any one?).